# How do I add a group to my community?

Tags: partner-communities, napili

I'm in the Napili template. When I try to add a page for Groups, I get an error message telling me that I have to have a group to access this component. But I don't see any place at all to create the first group.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks
Trish Perkins

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a Group Navigation Menu and Hopefully that will allow you to create Groups and avoid the alert .

[image]

Create a Group using new button

[image]

Also here is a little trick that will allow you to mange your template community with a little more native Salesforce funtionality.

1. In the Manager under Administration>Tabs add any areas that you offer in the template. (e.g. Chatter, Groups Knowledge, cases, etc.)
2. Go to your community url and replace the /s/ with this /_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupListPage

This will get you to the tabbed view of the community.
FYI, you'll probably need the "View Global Header" permission if you dont have that enabled already.

Comment: My partner found the problem. It was a permissions issue. Thanks Mohith!

Comment: What permissions?